# Is there anything similar to constexpr for C++03 in this context?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

Suppose I have a template class `A` with an integer template argument, and a class `B`, which derives from specialization of `A` (there could be many such derived classes with different specializations of `A`). I'd like to be able to ask `B` what template argument its base class has, and to call the corresponding static function from base class.

This is simple to do with C++11 `constexpr` keyword, but such keyword doesn't exist in C++03. So this code fails to compile with C++11 compiler on C++03-(supposedly)compatible line:

```
template<int N>
struct A
{
    static const int getN() { return N; }
    static constexpr int getNc() { return N; }

    static int g(const A& a) { return 123; }
};

struct B : public A<4>
{   
};

int main()
{
    A<B::getNc()>::g(B()); // OK in C++11
    A<B::getN()>::g(B()); // FAIL in any C++ version
}
```

So, the question is, how do I achieve the same in C++03? Maybe there's some syntactic sugar which would allow to avoid explicitly specifying the template parameter of `A` in `main()` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++03, a constant expression could be a static constant variable

```
static const int value = N;
```

or an enumerator

```
enum {value = N};
```

either of which you could access as

```
A<B::value>::g(B());
```

> Maybe there's some syntactic sugar which would allow to avoid explicitly specifying the template parameter of A

You could provide a non-member helper function:

```
template <class DerivedFromA>
int g(const DerivedFromA & a) {
    return A<DerivedFromA::value>::g(a);
}

// usage
g(B()); // equivalent to A<B::value>::g(B());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a function, use a `static const` data member: In `A`, put

```
static const int NVal = N;
```

and then `B::NVal` will give you the value of the `N` template parameter as a compile-time constant.